# C++ Find duplicate characters in a sorted string

Tags: c++, string, sorting, distinct

I have a problem that I really don't know how to solve.
I need to count how many DISTINCT characters are in my string.

For example.

/

INPUT: wjmzbmr

OUTPUT: 6

/

Since the 'm' is showed twice, it should count it once.

My main thought is to sort the string before checking the characters and then count the DUPLICATES. When I finish counting how many duplicates are there, I just subtract the string length with my counter of duplicates.

Here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    char temp;
    cin >> input;

    for(int i=0;i<input.length();i++)
    {
        for(int j=i;j<input.length();j++)
        {
            if(input[i] > input[j])
            {
                temp = input[i];
                input[i] = input[j];
                input[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    //SORTED STRING PRINT HERE
    cout<<input<<endl;

    int counter=0;
    for(int i=0;i<input.length()-1;i++)
    {
        if(input[i]==input[++i])
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    int new_length = input.length() - counter;
    cout<<"DUPLICATES: "<<counter<<endl;
    cout<<"STRING LENGTH: "<<input.length()<<endl;
    cout<<"WITHOUT DUPLICATES: "<<new_length<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

For some reasons this thing won't work on any string.
Let's say I have a string like this.

/

INPUT: pppppp

OUTPUT: 3

/

P.S. I've provided multiple outputs just to check where is the issue. I couldn't find it so I am writing here. Thank you guys in advance.

Comment: `input[++i]` modifies your counter variable `i`, meaning you skip half of the string

Comment: I would recommend [`std::unique`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) (requires grouped range - sorted range is grouped, for example) paired with [`std::distance`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance). It is a one-liner that solves your problem

Comment: Thank you sir, I managed to solve the issue. @UnholySheep

Comment: @n.m. Thank you for the response. That's how I solved the issue, I really didn't think about modifying my counter of the loop.

Comment: I think the problem is that you're confusing "duplicate" with "two characters that are the same"

Comment: Yeah I meant of "two characters that are the same".

EDIT: You got the idea however.

Answer (score 1):

"I need to count how many DISTINCT characters are in my string"

If, as you mention, your string is sorted, then it's fairly trivial. Use [std::unique](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique) in combination with `erase` to remove all duplicates. After that, your string holds only unique characters, so its `.size()` will be the count of unique characters.